# How can I build a dialog which is launched by a service?

Tags: android, android-alertdialog, homescreen

I think my problem is easy to fix for you. I have a service running in the background and starting an Intent which starts an activity, which opens a dialog.
Her is my code from the service:

```
Intent todialog = new Intent();
todialog.setClass(myService.this, openDialogInSleep.class);
todialog.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
startActivity(todialog);
```

and here is the activity:

```
import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.AlertDialog;
import android.os.Bundle;

public class openDialogInSleep extends Activity{

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    new AlertDialog.Builder(openDialogInSleep.this)
    .setTitle("huhu")
    .setNeutralButton("close", null);
}   
}
```

Finally the android manifest:

```
<activity android:name=".openDialogInSleep" android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Dialog"></activity>
```

My Problem is, that there is not shown the dialog with the title "huhu" and the button "close". There is only shown a dialog in a strange form which simply shows a part of my activityname.
What did I forget?
Please help me.

mfg. Alex

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You forget to chain in `show()` to actually show your dialog.

```
new AlertDialog.Builder(openDialogInSleep.this)
    .setTitle("huhu")
    .setNeutralButton("close", new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(DialogInterface arg0, int arg1) {
            openDialogInSleep.this.finish();
        }

    })
    .show();
```

Comment: ohhh thank you.. what a fail :D but there is one thing you could answer maybe, too. Now my dialog is shown, but if I click on close, there is still that window with the name of my activity. How could I write this button, that directly my home-secreen is shown and not first this window with the name of my activity?

Comment: Add a listener that closes your activity after you clicked the button. I edited the answer to show a short sample. In the same way add a `OnCancelListener`, in case your dialog gets cancelled with the back button.

Answer (score 1):

One thing you have missed is to call `show()` on the dialog generated by the AlertBuilder.

**UPDATE**

If I understand you correctly you don't want the activity to take control of the screen but rather just show the dialog?

If that is the case I don't think it is possible, the only way you can create a similar effect is by using a [`Toast`](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/notifiers/toasts.html) Message. This can be launched from your Service and you wouldn't require the activity at all.

Comment: thank you!! could you please look at my comment to the other answer?